# Add menu items/actions for multisite users who are registered on the network but do not have a role or capability in any sites

Tags: multisite, user-registration, api, capabilities, multisite-user-management

We've built a custom application ([Pressbooks](https://github.com/pressbooks/pressbooks)) that sits on top of WordPress multisite and transforms the multisite into a CMS for book publishing. A frequent flow for super admins is to invite a new user onto the network without adding them to a specific site. Let's call these users 'lowly users' because they're registered on the network but don't have a role in any of the network sites. Typically, our multisite users should be able to create new sites (book) OR use a custom 'cloning' routine to copy an openly licensed book/site from another Pressbooks to a newly registered site on their network via API.

Right now, lowly users can create a new site/book (using `wp-signup.php`), but the cloning routine is only accessible from the dashboard of an existing site on the network. This means that 'lowly users' can't use the cloning routine until they have a role in an existing site/book. We'd like to figure out a way to allow these lowly users to access and use the cloning routine (https://github.com/pressbooks/pressbooks/issues/1899).

Our first thought was make the cloning routine a sub page of the user profile page, which is visible for new users, rather than connecting it to a specific site/book. The problem we're facing is that it appears WordPress' `add_user_page` or `add_menu_page` or similar all require a capability argument (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) for the user, and these ‘lowly users’ don’t have any capabilities or roles in any sites. Users can however edit their profile and access the `wp-signup.php` file to create a new book.

Is there a way to register a sub-page of `user/profile.php` that these lowly users can access? Can we register our own action for `wp-signup.php` or `wp-login.php` that would let users clone books?

Should we hook into `user_register` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) and automatically give lowly users a role/capability (like subscriber) in the root site when they're first added to the network? Other ideas?